# How to add a key,value pair to a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I would like to be able to create a list of key, list pairs ( I think that's the most accurate way to describe my desired solution...)

I have a list of dictionaries and would like to add an element to each of these dictionaries that is a list of dictionaries (a mouthful, I know...).

To do this, I try to append key, value pairs to a list.  When I do this I get a syntax error ostensibly tripped on the colon in the key:value pair.

Here's my code:

```
d_l[0]['abilities'] = list()
d_l[0]['abilities'].append(abilities_m_l[job_row]['Element Name']:list()) # ability: stats about ability
```

where d_l is a list of dictionaries, 'abilities' is a key that I am creating.

And here's my error (the caret is on the colon (although in the past it's mislabeled the location of the error)).

```
d_l[0]['abilities'].append(abilities_m_l[job_row]['Element Name']:list()) # ability: stats about ability
                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
logout
```

If it helps, this is the desired overall structure:

```
{
    'job':'clerk', 'description': 'works in a bank', 'abilities': [
        'math': [
            'imp': {
                'Data Value': 4.5,
                'N' : 8,
                'S_E': 0.19                 
            },
            'level': {
                'Data Value': 4.75,
                'N': 8,
                'S_E': 0.25
            }
        ],
        'english': [
            'imp': {

            },
            'level': {

            }
        ],
        'dexterity': [
            'imp':{

            },
            'level': {

            }
        ]
    ]
},
```

Thanks so much! If you see obvious flaws in my arrangement just above (maybe I should be using a dictionary for abilities instead of a list?) please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to append a `dict` - note the `{}`, eg:

```
.append( {abilities_m_l[job_row]['Element Name']:list()} )
```

And it's more Pythonic and efficient to use `[]` for an empty list...

Comment: Thank you Jon! Very helpful. Why is it more efficient? Because I don't call a function?

Comment: @goldisfine mostly because `[]` can be optimised by the compiler, while `list` may take an iterable...

Comment: @goldisfine: Yes, `list()` is a global lookup (looking for an object named `list`), then a call (invoking the object associated with the name `list`). `[]` is immediately seen as an empty list object.